# Empty Payload. JSON content expected (guzzle, php, azur active directory and outlook)

Tags: php, outlook, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, guzzle

I am a student in programming and I have difficulties with my projects, little documentation meets my expectations and I would need help.
in this project I have to send from my application the token, the json flow on outlook to schedule a meeting

about Project : the principle is on a page to create a meeting which will then be linked to the outlook calendar this document helped me a lot https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http https://youtu.be/orVsKsRs2Us

(data is on another page)

the whole function

```php
    public function Postcalendrier($ID,$data) {

    $token=$_SESSION['token'];
    $ID=$_SESSION["ID"];
    $calendarGroup="/calendarGroups/{myID}/";
    $calendar="calendars/{myID}/events";
    $urlcalendar="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/".$ID;
    $url=$urlcalendar.$calendarGroup.$calendar;

    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token->access_token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ];

    $json = json_encode([$data])
      
 
    $reponse = $this->guzzle->request('POST', $url,['headers' => 
    $headers,'json' => $json],['debug' => true]);
    return $response->getStatusCode();
    }

    $data = array(
    "subject" => $Subject,
    "body" => array(
        "contentType" => "HTML",
        "content" => $Content
    ),
    "start" => array(
        "dateTime" => $StartDateTime."T".$StartHourTime.":00",
        "timeZone" => "$localDatetime"
    ),
    "end" => array(
        "dateTime" => $StartDateTime."T".$EndHourTime.":00",
        "timeZone" => "$localDatetime"
    ),
    "location" => array(
        "displayName" => $Location
    ),
    "attendees"=> [array(
        "emailAddress"=> array(
            "address"=> $addressmail,
            "name"=>$prenom
        ),
        "type"=> "required"
    )]
    );
```

I get this error message
Empty Payload. JSON content expected
so I tried with a different JSON but
I got this message instead and I don't really understand it

code UnableToDeserializePostBody message were unable to deserialize

this is my new json

```
   $json = [
            'json' =>  json_encode([$data])
        ];
```

thank you for your attention

Comment: What is `$data` supposed to be? And why are you trying to send this JSON as part of the request headers, from the error message it sounds like you are probably expected to send it as the request body instead ...?

Comment: welcome to so, your question lacks info, you need to add more info as specified by @CBroe

Comment: Hello @Golden, Can you please provide more information about what you are trying to and what you want to acheive?