# Access is denied. Check credentials and try again outlook API and microsoft graph

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, guzzle, azure-ad-graph-api

hello I'm part of a project and I'm having diffuclter
here is a previous post
[resolved since ]
: [Empty Payload. JSON content expected (guzzle, php, azur active directory and outlook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70831085/empty-payload-json-content-expected-guzzle-php-) azur-active-directory-and-out

a quick summary :
in this project you have to fill in a form that sends information
to schedule a meeting on outlook (date, place, title...).
the json stream and the sound token in the correct format. I am able to send the information but I do not have access
the code will be shown below for you to see.

and now I have this error:

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and 
try again."}}
```

here is the code of the pages

page 1 :

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    <div class="row" style="margin:10px;">
        <label for="Summary" class="col-sm-3">Subject :</label>
        <input type="text" class="col-sm-1 form-control" name="Subject" value="" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin:10px;">
        <label for="Description" class="col-sm-3">Content:</label>
        <input type="datetime" class="col-sm-1 form-control" name="Content" value="" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin:10px;">
        <label for="StartDateTime" class="col-sm-3">jour de la réunion :</label>
        <input type="date" class="col-sm-1 form-control" name="StartDateTime" value="" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin:10px;">
        <label for="StartHourTime" class="col-sm-3">debut de l'heure :</label>
        <select name="StartHourTime">
            <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
                if ($i < 10) {
                    $H = "0" . $i;
                } else {
                    $H = $i;
                }
                for ($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++) {
                    if ($j % 2 == 0) {
                        $m = "00";
                    } else {
                        $m = "30";
                    }
                    $rslt = $H . ":" . $m
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?= $rslt; ?>"><?= $rslt ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin:10px;">
        <label for="EndHourTime" class="col-sm-3">fin de l'heure :</label>
        <select name="EndHourTime">
            <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
                if ($i < 10) {
                    $H = "0" . $i;
                } else {
                    $H = $i;
                }
                for ($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++) {
                    if ($j % 2 == 0) {
                        $m = "00";
                    } else {
                        $m = "30";
                    }
                    $rslt = $H . ":" . $m
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?= $rslt; ?>"><?= $rslt ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin:10px;">
        <label for="Location" class="col-sm-3">localisation</label>
        <input type="text" class="col-sm-1 form-control" name="Location" value="" autocomplete="off"
               required>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-sm-3" style="margin:10px;">
        <button><a href="../porte.php">Retour</a></button>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

page 2 :

```
<?php

session_start();

require "../vendor/autoload.php";

use myPHPnotes\Microsoft\Auth;
use myPHPnotes\Microsoft\Handlers\Session;
use myPHPnotes\Microsoft\Models\User;

$token=$_SESSION['token'];
$access_token= $token->access_token;

$StartDateTime = $_POST["StartDateTime"];
$StartHourTime =$_POST["StartHourTime"];
$EndHourTime =$_POST["EndHourTime"];
$Subject=$_POST["Subject"];
$Content=$_POST["Content"];
$Location=$_POST["Location"];
$localDatetime = "Pacific Standard Time";

$user = new User;
$addressmail = $user->data->getUserPrincipalName();
$prenom=$user->data->getGivenName();
$ID=$user->data->getId();


$_SESSION["tenant"]= $tenant="common";
$_SESSION["client_id"]= $client_id="{ME}";
$_SESSION["client_secret"]= $client_secret="{ME}";
$_SESSION["callback"]= $callback="http://localhost:8080/callback.php";
$_SESSION["scopes"]= $scopes=["User.Read"];
$_SESSION["ID"]=$ID;


$data = array(
    "subject" => $Subject,
    "body" => array(
        "contentType" => "HTML",
        "content" => $Content
    ),
    "start" => array(
        "dateTime" => $StartDateTime."T".$StartHourTime.":00",
        "timeZone" => "$localDatetime"
    ),
    "end" => array(
        "dateTime" => $StartDateTime."T".$EndHourTime.":00",
        "timeZone" => "$localDatetime"
    ),
    "location" => array(
        "displayName" => $Location
    ),
    "attendees"=> [array(
        "emailAddress"=> array(
            "address"=> $addressmail,
            "name"=>$prenom
        ),
        "type"=> "required"
    )]
);

$user = new User;
$ID=$user->data->getId();

$microsoft = new Auth($tenant , $client_id, $client_secret,$callback, $scopes);
$microsoft->Postcalendrier($ID,$data);
?>
```

function Postcalendrier :

```
public function Postcalendrier($ID,$data)
{

    $token=$_SESSION['token'];
    $calendarGroup="/calendarGroups/{ME}";
    $calendar="/calendars/{ME}/events";
    $urlcalendar="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/".$ID;
    $url=$urlcalendar.$calendarGroup.$calendar;

    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token->access_token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ];

    var_dump(json_encode($data));
    var_dump($url);

    $reponse = $this->guzzle->request('POST', $url,[
        'headers' => $headers,
        'body' => json_encode($data),
        ],
        ['debug' => true]);

    return $reponse->getBody();
}
```

and finaly the autorisation on azure active directory :

[image]

I hope I have provided you with as much information as possible and that you can help me, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

> {"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied.
> Check credentials and  try again."}}

To resolve the above issue, ***When you are using `me` as end point in your code instead of that need to use `users/{USERID}`, as you have client credential flow*** .

For example:-

```
$_SESSION["tenant"]= $tenant="common";
$_SESSION["client_id"]= $client_id="{USER}";
$_SESSION["client_secret"]= $client_secret="{USERID}";
$_SESSION["callback"]= $callback="http://localhost:8080/callback.php";
$_SESSION["scopes"]= $scopes=["User.Read"];
$_SESSION["ID"]=$ID;
```

You have used in your `function Postcalendrier` - `$urlcalendar="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/".$ID;` instead of that use
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/usersID/calendar/getSchedule`

For Example:-

```
public function Postcalendrier($ID,$data)
{

    $token=$_SESSION['token'];
    $calendarGroup="/calendarGroups/{ME}";
    $calendar="/calendars/{ME}/events";
  $urlcalendar="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/usersID/calendar/getSchedule; //use this url to get the result
    $url=$urlcalendar.$calendarGroup.$calendar;

    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token->access_token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ];

    var_dump(json_encode($data));
    var_dump($url);

    $reponse = $this->guzzle->request('POST', $url,[
        'headers' => $headers,
        'body' => json_encode($data),
        ],
        ['debug' => true]);

    return $reponse->getBody();
}
```

For more information please refer this [***MS Q&A THREAD***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/228984/access-is-denied-check-credentials-and-try-again.html) as suggested by @[***vipulsparsh-MSFT***](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/1921276/vipulsparsh-msft.html)

and this ***Micro service Community discussion*** :[***Graph API - get calendar and events***](https://community.microfocus.com/it_ops_mgt/sws-oo/f/sws-oo_sup/310705/graph-api---get-calendar-and-events)